# Order by with Case statement so two columns are used to sort

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this Order By statement:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @SortID = 1 AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ProjectID END ASC,
CASE WHEN @SortID = 1 AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ProjectID END DESC
```

I have another column called DateSort. What I need is:

WHEN @SortID = 1 AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' ... I want to sort by ProjectID ASC, DateSort ASC

WHEN @SortID = 1 AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' ... I want to sort by ProjectID DESC, DateSort ASC

i.e. Regardless of whether ProjectID is being sorted ASC or DESC, I want the records to  also be sorted by DateSort ASC

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @SortID = 1 AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ProjectID END ASC,
CASE WHEN @SortID = 1 AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ProjectID END DESC,
DateSort ASC
```